# rpm requires range

Tags: rpm, rhel

I currently have two questions:

1) Is it possible to specify a range of a package in a rpm spec file? something like

package >= 1.0.0 and package < 1.0.50
meaning that it will pick up the latest package version closer to 1.0.50

2) Does somebody knows if yum will update to a package to a higher version even if the version specified in the spec file is lower? or is there something to avoid yum to upgrading to a higher version? This is my example to be more clear:

There are two packages in my repo:
package-1.0.5-1
package-2.0.10-1

and if my spec file for package! has the following requires
Requires: package > 1.0.5

When I do yum to install of packageA this means that it will install the higher version of 1.0.5 version or it will assume 2.0.10 is higher and will install that ? What I want to achieve is some sort of telling my package that just install as high as 1.0.5 release is and don't skip to the 2.x version.

I hope I made my self clear. Thanks for any tip or response you can give me

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you cannot specify the range, you may need to enter it on two lines of the spec file.

However, for the second question, `yum` will likely attempt to install `2.0.10` when asked to upgrade, and then complain about the conflict/requires (you didn't specify what the range was for). So it's going to annoy the users.

One solution, if you have control of the target package, is to have version 2 named `package2-2.0.10` which happens a lot. As far as rpm/yum is concerned, that's a totally different package and won't be seen as an option past `package-1.0.50`.

See [this wiki page](http://rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/MultipleVersions) for some more info.

Comment: First of all Thanks Aaron, for the first question I tried but for some reason I have package from 1-59 and when I put the range in twi lines in my spec file like >=1 <50 (to test) for some reason it pulls version 19 ??? not sure why it does this, it always tries that version for some reason. For the second one I need to maintain the same package as rolling back and ford will have issues because it will thinks is a different package.